# In heads-up Texas hold'em, what starting hands are "above average" pre-flop?

Tags: heads-up

In heads-up Texas hold'em what are the pockets that are "above average" pre-flop?

In other words, what would I need to hold to be infront of two random cards held by the other player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q7x or "The Computer Hand" is the median poker hand in Texas holdem. If you really want to analyse these things in more depth, I'd suggest getting [Pokerstove](http://www.pokerstove.com). You can run all hand matchups with numerous competing opponents through the free software.

Answer (score 5):

Q-7 offsuit actually has a little higher than 50% chance of winning against a random hand. The hands closest to a return of 0% (return being probability of winning subtract the probability of losing) are Q-5 offsuit and J-5 suited. Q-5 offsuit has the worst positive return, at about 0.24%. J-5 suited is the closest starting hand to 0% return, at about -0.03%. So if you are playing against a random hand, then Q-5 offsuit would be the worst hand to play that is still "above average".

[This table](http://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/2-player-game/) is useful if you want to see the rank order of the hands in a heads-up game.